# Why i get error 91 while using Intersect?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the `newcttnbr` row to intersect with the `By.Cells(2, i)` column.

Also `newcttnbr` is a single cell...

```
Sub NvxDetail()

Dim Ax As Worksheet: Set Ax = Workbooks("MODÈLE DE PROPOSITION DE CONTRAT DE SOUS-TRAITANCE.").Worksheets("Proposition de contrat")
Dim By As Worksheet: Set By = Workbooks("Suivi contrat fact").Worksheets("Détail")
Dim last_row As Integer: last_row = Ax.Cells(Ax.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Dim arng As Range: Set arng = Ax.Range(Ax.Cells(13, 1), Ax.Cells(last_row, 1))
Dim ByLastRow As Long: ByLastRow = By.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Dim newcttnbr As Range: Set newcttnbr = By.Cells(ByLastRow, 1)

    Ax.Range("C12").Copy
    newcttnbr.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       ActiveCell.Select


For i = 4 To 104
    For Each c In arng
        If By.Cells(2, i).Value = c.Value Then
           Intersect(newcttnbr(1, i), By.Cells(2, i)).Value = c.Offset(0, 5).Value
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: What do you expect from `newcttnbr(1, i)`, since `newcttnbr` range has a single cell?

Comment: I want to use the ```newcttnbr``` row to intersect with the ```By.Cells(2, i)``` column.

Comment: Using `newcttnbr.EntireRow` does what you say, but I have some doubts that you want checking the intersection of **only the last row** with that specific column... Can you better explain (**in words**) what you try doing?

Comment: The code will be executed only one time ( everytime i create a new contract).

Comment: It worked with EntireRow and EntireColumn... But i need to create another topic because using the last row is not the best way to make it.

Comment: this is what I wanted to ask, but I had a emergency... Do you want changing the value of the last row, for the column `i` in that cases? That's why it should be better to **clearly explain, in words** what you try doing...

Comment: It would be enough to use `newcttnbr(1, i).value = c.Offset(0, 5).Value`. The intersection will be a single cell, anyhow...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248535/discussion-between-salifgotem-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 2):

### VBA Lookup

- This is a slightly different approach using `Application.Match` instead of the inner loop.
- Use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of each module. It forces you to declare all variables; in your code e.g. `Dim i As Long` and `Dim c As Range` are missing.
- If you put the values in constants at the beginning of the code, it's much easier to tweak them. The code becomes more complicated though.
- In a nutshell, it looks in row `2` of the destination to find a match in column `A` of the source to copy the value from the matching row in column `F` (of the source) to the matching column in the first available row of the destination.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateNvxDetail()

    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const swbName As String _
        = "MODELE DE PROPOSITION DE CONTRAT DE SOUS-TRAITANCE."
    Const swsName As String = "Proposition de contrat"
    Const sfRow As Long = 13 ' first data row
    Const stCol As String = "C" ' title
    Const slCol As String = "A" ' lookup
    Const svCol As String = "F" ' value
    ' Destination
    Const dwbName As String = "Suivi contrat fact"
    Const dwsName As String = "Détail"
    Const dtCol As String = "A" ' title
    Const dlrgAddress As String = "D2:CV2" ' lookup (value depends on first r.)
 
    ' Source
 
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks(swbName)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(swsName)
    Dim slRow As Long ' in the title column
    slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, stCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim stCell As Range: Set stCell = sws.Cells(sfRow - 1, stCol)
    Dim slrg As Range ' lookup range (compare), it's a column
    Set slrg = sws.Range(sws.Cells(sfRow, slCol), sws.Cells(slRow, slCol))
    Dim svrg As Range ' value range (copy) ' it's a column
    Set svrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(svCol)
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(dwbName)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dwsName)
    Dim dFirstRow As Long ' in the title column
    dFirstRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dtCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    Dim dtCell As Range: Set dtCell = dws.Cells(dFirstRow, dtCol)
    Dim dlrg As Range ' lookup range (compare), it's a row
    Set dlrg = dws.Range(dlrgAddress)
    Dim dvrg As Range ' value range (write), it's a row
    Set dvrg = dlrg.EntireColumn.Rows(dFirstRow)

    ' Write the title?
    dtCell.Value = stCell.Value ' title?
    
    ' Lookup.
    
    Dim srIndex As Variant ' row
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim dcIndex As Long ' column
    
    For Each dCell In dlrg.Cells ' lookup
        dcIndex = dcIndex + 1
        ' This replaces the inner loop!
        srIndex = Application.Match(dCell.Value, slrg, 0) ' lookup
        If IsNumeric(srIndex) Then ' match found
            dvrg.Cells(dcIndex).Value = svrg.Cells(srIndex).Value ' value
        'Else ' match not found; do nothing
        End If
    Next dCell

    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Alright, I just check your code and tried it. First, it doesn't write the 1st data (number of contract) from 'Source ```Range(“C12”)``` to 'Destination last row. Also, I'm trying to verify if there is no other cell in 'Destination ```Range(“A:A”)``` before it runs the lookup part of the code. I'm still trying to understand every line of your code, this is really impressive there is a lot of information from the lookup part that I don't get.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it didn't intersect! Try the following:

```
Dim IntSect As Range
Set IntSect = Nothing
Set IntSect = Intersect(newcttnbr(1, i), By.Cells(2, i))
If IntSect Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No intersection"
Else
    IntSect.Value = c.Offset(0, 5).Value
End If
```

Comment: You was right the Intersect wasn't find

Answer (score 0):

Full code corrected using `EntireRow` and `EntireColumn` to find the intersect:

```
Sub NvxDetail()

Dim Ax As Worksheet: Set Ax = Workbooks("MODÈLE DE PROPOSITION DE CONTRAT DE SOUS-TRAITANCE.").Worksheets("Proposition de contrat")
Dim By As Worksheet: Set By = Workbooks("Suivi contrat fact").Worksheets("Détail")
Dim last_row As Integer: last_row = Ax.Cells(Ax.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Dim arng As Range: Set arng = Ax.Range(Ax.Cells(13, 1), Ax.Cells(last_row, 1))
Dim ByLastRow As Long: ByLastRow = By.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Dim newcttnbr As Range: Set newcttnbr = By.Cells(ByLastRow, 1)

    Ax.Range("C12").Copy
    newcttnbr.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       ActiveCell.Select


For i = 4 To 104
    For Each c In arng
        If By.Cells(2, i).Value = c.Value Then
           By.Cells(ByLastRow, i).Value = c.Offset(0, 6).Value
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't `By.Cells(ByLastRow, i).Value = c.Offset(0, 6).Value` handle it? No need for `newcttnbr`, *EntireRow*, *EntireColumn* or *Intersect*.

Comment: No words… Thank you, haha. Way easier, actually.