# VBA: (For... If... Then... Else...) Code always run Else even if "If" True

Tags: excel, vba

I want to intersect `By.Cells(2, i).EntireColumn` with `newcttnbr.EntireRow` in another way.

`newcttnbr` is the cell that contains the number of the contract in `By` Worksheet.
The number of the contract come from `Ax.Range("C12")`.

The actual code:

```
Sub NvxDetail()

    Dim Ax As Worksheet
    Set Ax = Workbooks("MODÈLE DE PROPOSITION DE CONTRAT DE SOUS-TRAITANCE.").Worksheets("Proposition de contrat")
    Dim By As Worksheet: Set By = Workbooks("Suivi contrat fact").Worksheets("Détail")
    Dim last_row As Integer: last_row = Ax.Cells(Ax.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim arng As Range: Set arng = Ax.Range(Ax.Cells(13, 1), Ax.Cells(last_row, 1))
    Dim ByLastRow As Long: ByLastRow = By.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    Dim newcttnbr As Range: Set newcttnbr = By.Cells(ByLastRow, 1)

    Ax.Range("C12").Copy
    newcttnbr.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Select

    For i = 4 To 104
        For Each c In arng
            If By.Cells(2, i).Value = c.Value Then
                Intersect(newcttnbr.EntireRow, By.Cells(2, i).EntireColumn) = c.Offset(0, 6)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next    
End Sub
```

I tried this:
The following code check if there is already a row with the same contract number... But it doesn't work.

```
Sub NvxDetail()

    Dim Ax As Worksheet: Set Ax = Workbooks("MODÈLE DE PROPOSITION DE CONTRAT DE SOUS-TRAITANCE.").Worksheets("Proposition de contrat")
    Dim By As Worksheet: Set By = Workbooks("Suivi contrat fact").Worksheets("Détail")
    Dim last_row As Integer: last_row = Ax.Cells(Ax.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim arng As Range: Set arng = Ax.Range(Ax.Cells(13, 1), Ax.Cells(last_row, 1))
    Dim ByLastRow As Long: ByLastRow = By.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    Dim newcttnbr As Range: Set newcttnbr = By.Cells(ByLastRow, 1)

    For x = 5 To 1000
        If By.Cells(x, 1) = Ax.Range("C12") Then
            MsgBox (" N° de contrat existant")

        Rem Doesn't stop there even if there is already a row that contains the same value

        Else
            Ax.Range("C12").Copy
            newcttnbr.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveCell.Select
            Exit For
           
            For i = 4 To 104
                For Each c In arng
                    If By.Cells(2, i).Value = c.Value Then
                        By.Cells(ByLastRow, i).Value = c.Offset(0, 6).Value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next    
End Sub
```

Comment: The `For i = 4 to 104` is never reached as you put an `Exit For` there. Clean up your indentations for the `If` and `For` loops - maybe you can then find the issue with the codeö

Comment: You need to check what gets compared here 'By.Cells(x, 1) = Ax.Range("C12")'.  The best way to do this is to read the cells into local variables so you can see what VBA is interpreting them as.

Comment: I've posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73946808) to your previous question. Check it out and share if it works or not.

Comment: @Ike Someone just edited the code but I'm still confused, i don't get what's wrong...

Comment: @freeflow it compares the write cells because it write the good value but multiple times.

Comment: You have to remove the first `Exit For` - I don't think that it makes sense at this point.

Comment: I just deleted it, but still not working, and I got like an infinite loop too.

Comment: Since your code doesn't do what you want it to, it's difficult to figure out exactly what you're trying to achieve here - it would help your question to explain step-by-step exactly what it is you want to automate with this code.